# How to execute string as js code in next js react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a string which contains js code to create a form and i want to execute that code
in a react component in next js

The variable formJsCode contains the js code. It is dynamic i.e coming from database.
The following code is not working well

```
const DForm = ( formJsCode ) => {
    return (
      
        <div>
            { eval( formJsCode) }
     </div>
       
    );
}

export default DForm
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to `eval` in a `useEffect`.

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const DForm = ({ formJsCode }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      eval(formJsCode);
    }, [formJsCode]);
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <DForm formJsCode="console.log('eval: Hello World!')" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Another solution is to append a script tag containing the JS:

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const DForm = ({ formJsCode }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.innerHTML = formJsCode;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, [formJsCode]);
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <DForm formJsCode="console.log('script tag: Hello World!')" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Evaluating in the JSX doesn't work because Next will try to execute the JS on the server. Instead, you should execute the JS client side when the client hydrates.